# Can someone explain what does the colon do in this case? and the overall definition of this code/

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Hi I'm learning Flutter and I came across this line of code which looks like this.

```
width: _width < 1000 ? _width / 1.2 : 833,
height: _width < 1000 ? _width / 2 : 500,
```

Can someone please explain what does the colon mean in this case?
Or just the overall meaning is fine.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a ternary operator, basically shorthand for if-then-else

i.e. "if _width is less than 1,000 return width divided by 1.2 else return 833"